# Read and write in a JSON file using python 2.x

Tags: python, html, json

I am writing a dictionary in a json file and I made a function to read the json and send it to a html file. My problem it's that it's not actually writing the dictionary. I really need help with this, because after a lot of thinking and searching I can't find what I am doing wrong.

I am making the dictionary in a file called queries

```
dict_scan_data = scan_data.to_dict(orient='records')

    data_load ={}
    data_load['noscan'] = dict_scan_data

    return json.dumps(data_load)


def updateJsonFiles():
    f = open('../site/json/data.json', 'w')
    f.write(calcProductionAsJSON())
    f.close()

# updateJsonFiles()
```

I made the read function like this:

```
import json
from queries import calcProductionAsJSON

def GetProductionTotals():
    """
    Return the production data as json
    """
    f = open('../site/json/data.json', 'r')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    return json.dumps(data)


def GetProductionTotalsLive():
    """
    Return the production data as json
    """
    return calcProductionAsJSON()
```

And in the html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data">
                <td>{{ item.Masina }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Productie }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Scanned }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Delta }}</td>
                </tr>
```

I am very new to python, so sorry if this question may seem easy or silly

Comment: Can you please explain what are you actually trying to achieve ?

Comment: Yes, the dictionary it's a query witch updates every 2 minutes. I want to the json file to be updated so I can display every time the latest result in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the GetProductionTotals(), it should return json.loads(data) instead of json.dumps(data) since json.dumps returns a string while json.loads returns back json from the string passed to it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I  Just modified with  json.loads(data) and it still doesn't updates the json file. Probably I am still doing something wrong

Comment: "it still doesn't updates the json file" , something gets written to the  file right? Could you paste the  content which is getting written?

Comment: It's not writing anything in the Json file. This is the reason I think I messed something in writing it

Comment: Yes, I printed the json and it's updating fine. The only problem it's that it's not writing it in the data.json

Comment: Try providing the absolute path of the file in the open file command or try this: f = open('path/to/file', 'w+'), which creates the file if not already present

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: What about the calcProductionAsJSON()? could you paste code? Maybe its not returning the data properly for the file to write.

Comment: calcProdictionAsJSON() is the my first function. I have def calcCuringProductionAsJSON(): inside here i am setting the time and then call the querry scan_data = querryNoSCan(start_time_prod,date_object,start_time_scan,date_object_scan). After this the dictionary from obove

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157123/discussion-between-rajkris-and-christian).

Comment: I saw this warning Relative import 'queries' should be 'backend.noscannapp.queries' in GetProductionTotals(). Could this be the problem why my app it's not writing anything in the json file?  this is how i import the   calcProductionAsJSON from queries

Comment: I dont think that will be an issue, for our current problem. Please confirm that dict_scan_data has some value or not.

Comment: Yes, dict_scan_data has values

Comment: And there is one thing each time the updateJsonFiles() is called, the data.json gets overwritten, even if it is an empty value. Maybe the file is getting overwritten by empty string

Comment: Yes, this is how it should be, but it's not updating. I manually wrote something in the data.json and theoretically it should have be overwritten with the json or with emty strings but nothing happens

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat

Answer (score 1):

json.dumps make string (JSON) from python dict 
json.**loads** load string (JSON) to dict

example (python 2.7.6)

```
>>> import json
>>> d = {'a': 'foobar'}
>>> json_from_d = json.dumps(d)
>>> json_from_d
'{"a": "foobar"}'
>>> 
>>> new_d_from_json = json.loads(json_from_d)
>>> new_d_from_json
{u'a': u'foobar'}
```

So in GetProductionTotals you should call json.loads(data)

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right, this is one of my mistakes. I modified it but it still doesn't work. I feel very stupid :)